# How to get CultureInfo from client machine?

Tags: c#, visual-web-gui

so this is question for 1mln$.

First of all, I'm developing web application in Visual WebGui. This is basically Winforms, but than application is converted to HTML5 and vualá.. web application. Anyway, I have a problem with DateTime formats. By default it is CultureInfo from server machine.

I can override this in web.config like that:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"  culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
```

Every dateformat will be german on every client machine. What I want is to make a web application, which will display Datetime format like on client machine in control panel.

Is it possible? I just can't find the solution.

Thanks for help,

Comment: What exactly is `Visual WebGui`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[1]);
```

Check this link for example [Multilingual Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6749/Multilingual-applications-using-C)

Comment: The correct culture is not always the second item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the uiculture and culture attributes of the globalization tag to auto. This will enable you to let the server decide the user's language according to his browser's settings and everything will happen automatically if you use localized resources.